# Pipeline Groovy error with custom step and libary

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following issue with my Jenkins 2.0 pipeline library and custom step

My `Jenkinsfile` from repo `X` contains:

```
@Library('acme-pipelines@dev')

import acme.jenkins.*

node {
    runGradle {
        version = '3.3'
        cmd = '--version'
    }
}
```

In repo `Y` (the pipeline library repo) i have `vars/runGradle.groovy` containing:

```
import acme.jenkins.*

def call(body) {
    def config = [:]
    def utils = new Utils()

    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    sh "${utils.getGradleBinPath(config.version)} ${config.cmd}"
}
```

Also in repo `Y` i have `src/acme/jenkins/Utils.groovy` containing:

```
package acme.jenkins

static String getGradleBinPath(String version = null) {
    if (!version) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException('No Gradle version supplied')
    }
    tool(version).concat('/bin/gradle')
}
```

When i run the pipeline i get the following error:

```
Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jenkins Library Development
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static softvision.jenkins.Utils.tool() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [3.3]
Possible solutions: wait(), run(), run(), find(), grep(), any()
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1506)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1492)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:18)
    at softvision.jenkins.Utils.getGradleBinPath(file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jenkins%20Library%20Development/builds/89/libs/softvision-pipelines/src/softvision/jenkins/Utils.groovy:7)
    at runGradle.call(/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jenkins Library Development/builds/89/libs/softvision-pipelines/vars/runGradle.groovy:11)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:6)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor273.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is the same error if i wrap the `getGradleBinPath` method in a class named `Utils`, with or without the `static` keyword prefix for the method, i also tried to `implement Serializable` when using the class version, but i get the same error.

If i remove the `static` keyword in the scripted version it works fine, all of the example code scenarios and above mentioned yield the same error.

I'm pretty new to Groovy so please forgive me if this is not related to Jenkins, or very trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access pipeline standard steps directly in classes\scripts under `src` directory. You should pass the steps to constructor/setter or as method parameter.
Something like that should work
`src/acme/jenkins/Utils.groovy`

```
package acme.jenkins
class Utils implements Serializable {

    def steps

    Utils(steps) {
        this.steps = steps
    }

    String getGradleBinPath(String version = null) {
        if (!version) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException('No Gradle version supplied')
        }
        steps.tool(version).concat('/bin/gradle')
    }
}
```

and then in `vars/runGradle.groovy`

```
//..
def utils = new Utils(steps)
//...
```

See [Accessing steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps).

Note that `steps` is a standard global variable that hold pipeline steps.

Comment: Somehow i overlooked this in the documentation. Your implementation worked but with a small edit, i also needed to implement the `Serializable` interface or else i would get a `java.io.NotSerializableException` exception on `acme.jenkins.Utils`, can you please edit your answer so i can mark it as excepted?

Comment: As a side note, it would be helpful if somebody can step in and also explain why it would not work without implementing the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you do not need to suspend and resume your Jenkins Pipelines that use the `runGradle` custom step, you can add the `@NonCPS` decorator to the `call` method in `vars/runGradle.groovy` in which case you would not need to implement the `Serializable` interface on the `Utils` class.

Comment: @Nicolae this is because Jenkins Pipeline uses CPS transformation. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I thought it should be `new Utils(this)` ?

Comment: I wonder how jenkins pipeline handles the delegation. If you pass `this` into the class as `script` or `steps`, `script.dir(mydir) { }` could work, but `script.dir.curry(mydir)` would raise a property not found exception.